# VB 2010 express Progressbar

Tags: vb.net

I have been using visual basic 2010 express for about 2 weeks now and im trying to make a RPG game. And until now everything have been going smooth. But i can't get my label to show the progressbars value. Can smoebody please help me?

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub ProgressBar1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click
        Label2.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & ("")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        HouseBuy.show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        HouseSell.show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
        Label2.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & ("")
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 1000 Then
            MsgBox("You cant get any more money")
        ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value = 0 Then
            MsgBox("You are out of money")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        mymap.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When you say you can't get the label to show the progress bars value what do you mean. Do you expect that the label will be updated each time the progress bar updates because looking at your code it is only set up to update the when you click on either the progress bar or the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProgressBar component(instanse of the class) has 2 propeties that you need:
Value
and Maximum.
The first you need initialised Maximum property and second increment your Value property.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps storing the player's money as a variable would be better. That way the progress bar and label text would update from the value of the variable and you are not storing player's money in the progress bar value.

Here's a quick example of how I might have done it:

```
    Dim characterMoney As Integer 'Global variable - Player Money

Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles but_IncreaseMoney.Click
    changeMoney(60) 'Increase by 60
End Sub
Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles but_DecreaseMoney.Click
    changeMoney(-60) 'Decrease by 60
End Sub

Sub changeMoney(ByVal valToChange) 'Could change to a function (return true or false)

    Dim checkMoneyVal As Integer
    checkMoneyVal = (characterMoney + valToChange) 'Check Val after change

    If checkMoneyVal > 1000 Or checkMoneyVal < 0 Then 'If after the change 
        MessageBox.Show("You would have too much or too little money!") 'Its an invalid amount. 
    Else
        'Player has enough money.
        characterMoney = characterMoney + valToChange 'Increase/Decrease their money
    End If

    Label1.Text = characterMoney  'Update the label text
    ProgressBar1.Value = characterMoney 'Update the progress value
End Sub
```

So in this example. If you wanted to increase or decrease the money of the player. It would calculate what the money would be after the change. If it will be greater than 1000 or less than zero it wouldn't let the change happen - instead returning an error message.
Otherwise, if after the change is valid then it would increase the money by the amount.

Once a money change has happened - The progress bar and label would update.

Comment: Charlie when i use your changemoney idea (which by the way are great!) then it won't stop saying you would have too much or too little money. Do you got a idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. If you could give me an example on what your inputting then I could test it as well. If you wanted to just 'update' the progress bar and label without actually changing the money. You could make a new subroutine called "refreshMoney" and make it update just Label and progressBar - without any money change. You could also just pass the value '0'. (I could give you an example if this is what you mean)

Comment: it's nit necessary to change anything any longer. I got it to work with the first code you wrote. Thank you!